# ERROR: could not create directory "base/16386": No space left on device

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, postgresql-9.3

I receive the same error when I try to create a database with

```
CREATE DATABASE dwh;
```

and

```
createdb dwh;
```

namely:

```
createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  could not create directory "base/16385": No space left on device
```

and

```
ERROR:  could not create directory "base/16386": No space left on device
```

I am using a postgres AMI on aws  (PostgreSQL/Ubuntu provided by OpenLogic)https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/ordering/ref=dtl_psb_continue?ie=UTF8&productId=13692aed-193f-4384-91ce-c9260eeca63d&region=eu-west-1

provisioned with m2.xlarge machine, which should have 17GB RAM and 350GB SSD

Comment: I suspect that your default directories are not pointing to the drive with 350 Gbytes (assuming that the obvious possibility that the drive is full is not true).

Comment: What does "show data_directory;" return? And is this directory on your 350 GB disk?

Comment: As talked about in other answers, you may not have the 350GB disk available to you. Historically AWS EC2 will not mount a disk (other than root filesystem) on system boot, this is because EBS is often not ready at the time of boot and will cause problems, and local disks (your 350GB SSD) follow the same consideration. You may need to mount the 350GB SSD first then reconfigure Postgres. Be warned: Local disks (given by virtual machines) are Ephemeral, meaning they will be destroyed on Stop/Start. You may wish to consider using an EBS device for more permanent storage.

Comment: Please read AWS documentation on Instance Store (ephemeral storage) here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the description provided, you have not mapped your Postgres `/data` directory to your actual 350GB partition.

**If you are running production server, 1st of all -  try to clean up the logs (`/pg_log` folder) to save disk space and bring up the box to normal operation AND create backup of your database.**

Run `df -h` to see disk devices utilization and `lsblk` what is mounted to your disk.  It highly likely, that AWS by default gave you not extended 350GB volume. You have 2 options:

- Add new disk take a look at [**Ubuntu add new drive procedure**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive) and map it to your Postgres `/data` folder
- Try to do perform resize of the existing file system with `resize2fs`, relevant [**answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/109360) can be found at AskUbuntu